# How to infer noise map from noisy data?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, bayesian, inference, noise

I am given noisy measurements of the solution of a PDE at different times, each measurement is drawn from a Gaussian distribution having as mean the solution of the PDE at that time and a standard deviation varying with time.

This is a picture of the measurements, you can better understand how the deviation is augmenting with time: [image]

I want to predict the noise by inferring the map of the standard deviation, how could I do that ?

Comment: Usually, noise is defined as the part that cannot be predicted, so what exactly do you mean by “predicting the noise”?

Comment: maybe it could be better frased as 'inferring the map of the noise', which means being able given this data to estimate sigma at a certain t

Comment: What do you mean by that? Learning the variability?